# Positioning issue when display items like gallery items

Tags: html, css

I have some data(boxes) that should display like gallery items (like in any shoping site), the issue is height of each box is not same because of its content and each row has 4 items(boxes), let say if one of the box from first has height 300px and all others has height 250px then next item in next start from end of max height in first row, i did not want it like this, i did not want these empty spaces, every box in next row should display under box from first row

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.flex-container {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.flex-item {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 122px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 2flex item 2flex item 2flex item 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are trying to achieve an effect I know as masonry. It's pretty complex to do yourself, but there are good plugins. Check this out: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: this link is not working at my side :(

Comment: give some hint how i do it, without this plugin

Comment: ok link is working now, thanks, let me try it

Comment: [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/), [bootstrap-waterfall](https://github.com/Mystist/bootstrap-waterfall) (pintrest-like script) or CSS columns. Here is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43118578/jquery-load-more-masonry-elements/43164420#43164420) I answered recently, which, among others, lists your possible options.

Comment: @kapser your coment was help full, thanks

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu thanks you give lot more options to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect you're looking for is called Masonry, or the Pinterest effect as far as I know. [This is a good plugin for it.](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Here's your code with masonry implemented: https://jsfiddle.net/jwjkt933/

jQuery code used for initialising masonry:

```
(function($) {
  $('.flex-container').masonry({
    columnWidth: 152,
    gutter: 10,
    itemSelector: '.flex-item'
  });
})(jQuery);
```

This example also needs jQuery, although you can also initialise masonry with pure JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with flex but not in rows. You'll have to use `flex-direction: column;` and `align-content` property. Check this fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/4evoq3nt/1/

Comment: hi, @Varin only problem i have with this is height, i can't use height because content is dynamic and i am not sure about height

Comment: This solution grows horizontally. Keep adding items and you get a horizontal scrollbar instead of a vertical one, which is ***not what the average user expects*** from this layout. Therefore your solution does not answer the question. I doubt you personally would ever use this when having an unknown stream of items to be displayed in columns. `Flexbox` cannot be used for `masonry`/`pinterest` layout. Consider CSS columns, but that has a major content reflow problem on resize or adding more items.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a minimum height and the height a specific way for flex-item, that way despite the content, you will always get the same sized boxes throughout flex-container, as show here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.flex-container {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.flex-item {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 122px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  height:100%;
  min-height: 75px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 2flex item 2flex item 2flex item 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

***Make sure to take note of the min-height and height parameters used in the example above***